# How to set two relative position div align top

Tags: html, css

See the full code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jx2jc0xv/

```
.one {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:70px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.two {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I want to set **.one** and **.two** divs align top where **.two** div will be responsive width and height.

Here I used in **.two** div `width: 80%;` which is not full width also.

Comment: Huh? What do you want?

Comment: I want to set two divs align top.

Comment: How and why down vote me? Explain me first where is my problem please.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.

Comment: "Thank u sir David." That's hillarious. You've just been knighted :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```css
.one {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width:70px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  width:80%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: I am trying.. Thank u sir.

Comment: Thank u sir Kuba Rakoczy